# C typedef: parameter has incomplete type

Tags: c, gcc

GCC 3.4.5 (MinGW version) produces a warning: parameter has incomplete type for line 2 of the following C code:

```
struct s;
typedef void (* func_t)(struct s _this);
struct s { func_t method; int dummy_member; };
```

Is there a way to fix this (or at least hide the warning) without changing the method argument's signature to (struct s *)?

**Note:** 
As to why something like this would be useful: I'm currently tinkering with an object-oriented framework; 'method' is an entry in a dispatch table and because of the particular design of the framework, it makes sense to pass '_this' by value and not by reference (as it is usually done)...

Comment: Which version of GCC? That exact snippet of code (plus a main function) gives me no warnings with the GCC included with Ubuntu, which is 4.3.2. Is there something else involved that is causing the warning?

Comment: I'm currently stuck with the MinGW version of gcc, which is 3.4.5(?). But nice to know that the problem might eventually just go away...

Comment: GCC 3.4.6 complains under -Wall; GCC 4.3.2 does not - Solaris 10.

Comment: How would you ever use this structure/function?  Is this a maximally reduced example (generally a good thing - though you might have gone one step to far in the minimization), or is it a fabricated test case?  I can't see how I'd get a useful result out of a structure or function like this.

Comment: Why does it make sense to pass by value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning seems to be a bug with the current MinGW version of gcc. Contrary to what Adam said, it *is* valid C99 - section 6.7.5.3, paragraph 12 explicitly allows this:

> If the function declarator is not part of a definition of that function, parameters may have incomplete type and may use the [*] notation in their sequences of declarator specifiers to specify variable length array types.

There seems to be no way to instruct (this version of) gcc to not print this warning - at least *I* could not find a switch which worked - so I'm just ignoring it for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't quite do this easily - according to the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), Section 6.7.5.3, paragraph 4:

> After adjustment, the parameters in a parameter type list in a function declarator that is
>   part of a definition of that function shall not have incomplete type.

Your options are, therefore, to have the function take a pointer to the structure, or to take a pointer to a function of a slightly different type, such as a function taking unspecified parameters:

```
typedef void (* func_t)(struct s*);  // Pointer to struct
typedef void (* func_t)(void *);     // Eww - this is inferior to above option in every way
typedef void (* func_t)();           // Unspecified parameters
```

Comment: But there is no definition of that function, is there...just declarations?

Comment: Thanks. Your last suggestion actually does what I want, but then I'll loose all type information (and get a warning when compiling with -Wstrict-prototypes) - so I'll most likely just stick with the version I got...

Comment: i think jonathan is right. it may be invalid in c (i don't know. i only know in C++ it would be valid), but the statement you shown us doesn't make it invalid. in his code. the function declarator is not part of a definition. it's merely declaring the function.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to GCC 4 seems like it should work. MinGW version 4.3.0: http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=2435&package_id=241304&release_id=596917

Answer (score 0):

Hiding warnings is generally pretty easy - just look at the help for your particular compiler.

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001838

Note that suppressing warnings is generally not something I would advocate.

Comment: Um, I know.  But the person who asked the question asked about hiding the warning.  I just pointed out how to do it.  It seems a bit unfair for me to be downvoted for answering that part of his question...

Answer (score -1):

You want to call it with a function pointer.  Why not use a void pointer instead?

```
typedef void (*func_t)(void*);
```

You MIGHT be able to pass a loosely-typed function pointer as well; I don't have a compiler on hand.

```
typedef void (*func_t)(void (*)());
```

Comment: "You want to call it with a function pointer" Actually, I don't. struct s contains other members as well - I'll clarify the question in a minute...